# How does (id)sender work in cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

The following code works good for me:

In the init method of a menu layer:

```
CCMenuItemFont *item1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Level 1" target: self selector: @selector(startLevel:)];
item1.userData = (__bridge void*) ([NSNumber numberWithInt:1]);
...//create menu and add in the item1


-(void)startLevel: (CCMenuItem *)sender
{
    NSNumber *number = sender.userData;
    ...
}
```

My questions are:

- I didn't pass item1 when call the method startLevel: how does it know that the sender is item1?
- is it written into selector? or is it written in cocoa?

Answer (score 2):

CCMenuItem passes itself as parameter to this selector. Details are in CCMenuItem source code.

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean only here I can omit passing itself as parameter, and in other places you need to add itself as parameter manually?

Comment: I don't understand you. What do you mean with "omit passing itself as parameter"? in `[CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:target:selector:]` you set target object and method of target object which will be called when this menu item activates. I think you are confused as what `self` keyword means. In Objective C, `self` is a way to refer to “the object that’s received this message.” So when you use `self` in a method of your layer, it means this layer. When CCMenuItem uses `self` in its method, it means this CCMenuItem.

Comment: When you do `[CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Level 1" target: self selector: @selector(startLevel:)];` in a method of your layer, you essentially tell your CCMenuItem "when you are activated, call such-and-such method of such-and-such object", and as "such-and-such object" is your layer, you use `self` keyword for it.

Comment: Thank you, though not fully understand of the explaining of "self" part, I'll remember your words. I believe it'll be helpful sometime in the future after taking more practice in coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding omitting passing itself as a parameter, do you mean like...

```
- (void) pushedStart : (id) sender
{
    //start game
}
```

but you can't do

```
[self pushedStart];
```

because it needs a parameter?  If so, what you can do this:

```
id junkID;
[self pushedStart: junkID];
```

JunkID will initialize to whatever the hell it is an unassigned ID assigns to, so you pass it as a reference and just don't use it for anything, which is good if you want to have a "start game" button but have the game automatically start inside of a timer or whatever else you're doing with your buttons

As a side note, and getting more into the guts of cocoa, the way it KNOWS (and what YOU must not forget) is that colon.  When you call a function you put the variable after a colon [self eat: food];

When you put together the menu item you set it up with target:self, which makes the button use itself (not the layer "self" you use when you call [self eatABanana]) as a target.  The button push of

```
menuButton = target:self selector:@selector(pushButton:)
```

is represented like

```
[self pushButton:menuButton]
```

If you forgot that colon, it's the same as calling a function and not passing the variable, which doesn't give a very helpful error message insofar as it doesn't help you locate where the problem is occurring.  I've spent hours upon hours chasing down memory crashes resulting from writing @selector(startGame) instead of @selector(startGame:) in those damn menu buttons.  I always feel stupid when I finally figure it out.

Comment: why use garbage values when you can use nil? :)

Comment: exactly, just use nil, never garbage. Though in fairness with ARC enabled junkID is guaranteed to be nil.